# How to create a new matrix by subtracting columns in a given matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

```
mat_sub <- function(x){
nc <- ncol(x)
  for (i in 1:nc){
    s <- x[,i]-x[,i-1]
 } 
 Z <- cbind(x,s)
 Z}
```

Please help in understanding where I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you start with `i = 1`, then `i - 1` is 0 and this column doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments you need to start the `for` loop at the second column, else `i - 1` gets zero and that can't be subsetted. The other issue is `s` which gets overwritten in each iteration. You want to define a two-dimensional `array` (i.e. a matrix) beforehand, with dimensions of your original matrix minus one column, that gets filled in each iteration.

You may want to correct your code to:

```
mat_sub <- function(x) {
  nc <- ncol(x)
  s <- array(NA, dim(x))[, -nc]
  for (i in 2:nc) {
    s[, i - 1] <- x[, i] - x[, i - 1]
  } 
  Z <- cbind(x, s)
  Z
}

m <- matrix(1:12, 3, 4)
mat_sub(m)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10    3    3    3
# [2,]    2    5    8   11    3    3    3
# [3,]    3    6    9   12    3    3    3
```

Alternatively, in R you may simply do vectorized calculations including subtracting matrices.

```
cbind(m, m[, -1] - m[, -ncol(m)])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10    3    3    3
# [2,]    2    5    8   11    3    3    3
# [3,]    3    6    9   12    3    3    3
```

Comment: thanks understood. Actually I am new to R, so basic mistakes seems to happen. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are over-writing `s` every time in the loop. Also you start the loop with 1 in which case there is no `i-1` i.e 0th column.

You can try :

```
mat_sub <- function(x){
  nc <- ncol(x)
  x[, 2:nc] - x[, 1:(nc-1)]
}
```

Using an example :

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(sample(16), 4)
mat

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   15   10    4   11
#[2,]   16    2   12   13
#[3,]    3    6    7    8
#[4,]   14    5    1    9

mat_sub(mat)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   -5   -6    7
#[2,]  -14   10    1
#[3,]    3    1    1
#[4,]   -9   -4    8
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying. however i see u have used set.seed() function. Any specific reason for using that.

Comment: `set.seed` is used for reproducibility so when you run `mat <- matrix(sample(16), 4)` you get the same matrix numbers as mine.

Comment: Ok. thanks understood that after using set.seed function the result will remain consistent when creating a matrix or data frame from a sample. But what does 123 signify.

Comment: Nothing. You can use any number. Read `?set.seed`